# KeyError while appending dictionary

Tags: python, keyerror

I am getting a key error while trying to add a variable from a parsed pcap file.

Here I am trying to get the last time stamp but I get a key error

```
KeyError: 'UPD'


lst_timestamp = {}

for ts, buf in packets:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    protocol_number = ip.p
    traffic_type = protocoltype.proto[protocol_number]
    if traffic_type not in traffic_types:
        traffic_types.append(traffic_type)

    if traffic_type in no_packets: # check the key is in the dictionary
        no_packets[traffic_type] += 1
    else:
        no_packets[traffic_type] = 1
        
    if traffic_type not in fst_timestamp:
        fst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
    
    if traffic_type in lst_timestamp:
        lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
```

The error is occurring here:

```
if traffic_type in lst_timestamp:
    lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
```

I am fairly new to python so I have tried to find why this error occurs but I can't figure it out, any help would be much apricated.

Full code.

```
import dpkt
import socket
from tabulate import tabulate
import protocoltype

def main() -> list:    
    """parse pcap"""
    pcap_file = "evidence-packet-analysis.pcap"

    packets = []
    open_file = open(pcap_file, "rb")    
    for ts, buf in dpkt.pcap.Reader(open_file):
        packets.append((ts, buf))
    open_file.close()

    print(f"'{pcap_file}' Successfully Read")

    table(packets)

def table(packets):
    traffic_types = []
    no_packets = {}
    fst_timestamp = {}
    lst_timestamp = {}

    for ts, buf in packets:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        ip = eth.data
        protocol_number = ip.p
        traffic_type = protocoltype.proto[protocol_number]
        if traffic_type not in traffic_types:
            traffic_types.append(traffic_type)

        if traffic_type in no_packets: # check the key is in 
the dictionary
            no_packets[traffic_type] += 1
        else:
            no_packets[traffic_type] = 1
        
        if traffic_type not in fst_timestamp:
            fst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
    
        if traffic_type in lst_timestamp:
            lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
        
    rows = []
    for traffic_type in traffic_types:
        rows.append([traffic_type, no_packets[traffic_type], 
fst_timestamp[traffic_type], lst_timestamp[traffic_type], 0])

    print(tabulate(
        rows,
        headers=["traffic_type", "no_packets", "fst_timestamp", 
"lst_timestamp", "mean_packet_length"]
    ))


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

The module protocoltype is just a dictionary linking protocol numbers to protocol type

Comment: Please paste the minimum reproducible code with the full traceback of error.

Comment: how do you know the error is in the line you `if traffic_type in lst_timestamp:  lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts`? Please paste the traceback of the error also?

Comment: Because when the error occurred when I added that in, and disappeared when removed it.   File "F:\Uni(N)\Scripting\CW\CW.py", line 51, in table
    rows.append([traffic_type, no_packets[traffic_type], fst_timestamp[traffic_type], lst_timestamp[traffic_type], 0])

KeyError: 'UDP'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Error is not here:

```
if traffic_type in lst_timestamp:
    lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
```

It just happened because you added this code. But the main reason it is occurring is here:

```
rows.append([traffic_type, no_packets[traffic_type], 
fst_timestamp[traffic_type], lst_timestamp[traffic_type], 0])
```

Let me explain:

Say you have a key 'UDP' for `traffic_type` in the list `traffic_types`:

then:

if the `traffic_type` is not in `no_packets`, or `fst_timestamp`: you are inserting it.

```
if traffic_type in no_packets: # check the key is in 
the dictionary
    no_packets[traffic_type] += 1
else:
    no_packets[traffic_type] = 1

if traffic_type not in fst_timestamp:
    fst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts
```

But if the key `traffic_type` is not in lst_timestamp, then you are not inserting it, you are just incrementing if it already exists.

I am assuming key `traffic_type` i.e. 'UDP' is not is `lst_timestamp`, so you nothing about it in the code.

But then comes this line:

```
rows.append([traffic_type, no_packets[traffic_type], 
    fst_timestamp[traffic_type], lst_timestamp[traffic_type], 0])
```

Here you are accessing `lst_timestamp[traffic_type]`, i.e. `lst_timestamp['UPD']` which is not in the list.

Hence, you are getting the **KeyError: 'UPD'** while appending the dictionary.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Comment: Ah yes I understand. So how do I fix this so that UDP is a key because i'm struggling to see why the code that creates the list is incorrect

Comment: @MilesB  just add `if not in lst_timestamp: lst_timestamp[traffic_type] = ts` like other conditions. Also please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.